# Problem in Breadth First Search

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

```
cin>>t;

while (t--)
{

    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;

    if (n==m)
        cout<<"0\n";
    else
    {
        //Breadth First Search Tree:
        queue <gnode*> gqueue;

        bft_data bft=bft_data();


        list<gnode>* gp;
        list<gnode>::iterator it;

        gp=_gfind(graph,n);// finds list containing gnode with n value
        gnode* st=gfind(gp,n),*tmp,*_st;//finds gnode with n value
        _st=st;

        bft.w[st->v]=0;
        bft.pn[st->v]=NULL;
        bft.c[st->v]=1;

        gqueue.push(st);

        while (!gqueue.empty())
        {
            st=gqueue.front();
            gqueue.pop();

            gp=_gfind(graph,st->v);

            it=(*gp).begin();
            for (++it;it!=(*gp).end();it++)//initialized with ++it to skip fist element of list
            {
                tmp=&(*it);
                // cout<<tmp->v<<"\n";
                //  getchar();
                if (bft.c[tmp->v]==0)
                {
                    bft.pn[tmp->v]=st;
                    bft.c[tmp->v]=1;
                    bft.w[tmp->v]=bft.w[st->v]+1;

                    gqueue.push(tmp);
                }
            }

        }


       if(bft.w[m]!=SIZE)
        cout<<bft.w[m]<<"\n";
        else
        cout<<"Impossible\n";
bft.~bft_data();
    }
}
```

This code snippet to calculate the distance b/w the node with value n and m by constructing bfs tree.But somehow bft tree constructed in first iteration of outer while loop retains its vlaue ,further iteration of while loop have no effect on the bft

here graph is of type `vector<list<gnode>>`

bfs is object of class bft_data:

```
class bft_data
{
public:
int w[SIZE],c[SIZE];
gnode* pn[SIZE];

bft_data()
{
    memset(w,SIZE,SIZE);
    memset(c,0,SIZE);
    memset(pn,NULL,SIZE);
}

 };
```

Comment: Anyone with suggestion on more efficient implementation of graph with vector<llist<gnode>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked through your first code extract, but the second extract might explain the problem: the third argument to memset is a byte count, so you must multiply it by the size of the array element:

```
memset(w,SIZE,SIZE * sizeof(int));
memset(c,0,SIZE * sizeof(int));
memset(pn,NULL,SIZE * sizeof (gnode*));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TonyK that worked. I was stuck with that problem for hours, what a silly mistake.

Comment: can you please look at my implementation of graph and breath first tree using vector<llist<gnode>> and class bft_data.I just want to know if it is efficient.This is the first time I am implementing a graph.